# Why does cos(x) give me a result of x as x was in radians?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I am using Python but there is something strange. Why does cos(x) give me a result of x as was in radians? while cos(radians(x)) gives the answer as x was in degree

for example :

```
>>> cos(75)
0.9217512697247493
```

but the truth is if 75 is in degree, then cos(75) = 0.26

```
>>> cos(radians(75))
0.25881904510252074
```

but the truth is if 75 is in radians, then cos(75) = 0.90

I am wrong ? why is that happening ?

Comment: From the docs, `Return the cosine of x (measured in radians).`

Comment: The calculator on my machine gives `cos(75)` as 0.9217512697…  Using `bc -l <<< 'cos(75)'` yields 0.92175126972474931639 (adding a leading zero).  Your 0.90 seems to be a poor approximation to what you should be expecting.

Comment: Every language I know uses radians for trig functions; none use degrees as inputs. FORTRAN, C, C++, Java, C#, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, Scala - you get the idea.  Make it easy - find a language that uses radians for angles natively.  I'll be surprised if there is one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `cos(75)` means "the cosine of 75 radians". (See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions).)
- `radians(75)` means "convert 75° to radians", i.e. "the number of radians that's equivalent to 75°". (See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#angular-conversion).)
- so `cos(radians(75))` means "the cosine of {the number of radians that's equivalent to 75°} radians", i.e. "the cosine of 75°".